# Why was pidof and pgrep removed from OpenSuse 15.5?

Tags: opensuse, distributions, pgrep, pidof

In openSuse leap 15.5, there are no packages offering pidof?

SysVinit-tools package were part of the OS bundle previosuly, but was removed in 15.5. So, is there any alternates without installing sysVinit package (or) need to install the packages manually?

Also any other distros as well planning to remove the package(sysvinit-tools)?

Comment: Did you try the version from the OSS Repo for 15.5. This is for x86_64: http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.5/repo/oss/x86_64/sysvinit-tools-2.99-1.1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: An obvious answer, regarding the removal of sysvinit: openSUSE is a distribution using systemd. There is a number of distributions not using systemd, but other init systems. That said, sysvinit is considered suboptimal and obsolete even in those distributions, which use more sophisticated init systems, such as OpenRC, runit, s6 etc.

Comment: You can still install `sysvinit-tools` via zypper (`zypper install sysvinit-tools`) or YAST. My opensuse-leap 15.5 can still install these tools. PS you can search for packages containing a specific command (like `pidof`) using `cnf pidof`

Answer (score 0):

In the Files section of the [`procps`](https://opensuse.pkgs.org/15.5/opensuse-oss-x86_64/procps-3.3.15-150000.7.31.1.s390x.rpm.html) package for OpenSUSE Leap 15.5, `pgrep` does appear.

Regarding SystemV, The release notes for [SLES15-SP4](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/15-SP4/index.html#jsc-SLE-7690) states that:

> Support for System V init.d scripts is deprecated and will be removed with the next major version of SUSE Linux Enterprise Server.

I assume this is also true for openSUSE.

Though I didn't find any explicit announcement for openSUSE, the writing has been on the wall for a long time.

See also:

[Packaging init scripts](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Packaging_init_scripts):

> Warning: SysV-style Initscripts are either deprecated or not supported
> in all currently maintained openSUSE releases.

[systemd-sysvcompat](https://software.opensuse.org/package/systemd-sysvcompat):

> Please note that the content of this package is considered as
> deprecated.